What word would you call something sticking out from a surface? (see photos inside)
What word would you call something sticking out as in the pictures below?
(1) 
(2) 
(3) 
(4) 
I found some words in dictionaries: "projection", "ledge". But I don't know which one is appropriate for these pictures.
Update:
(1) depicts a stone sticking out from the rock with the hands of a climber on it.

Yes, we can see for ourselves what (1) is! I don't think there is one single word for all these shapes. (1) is a (very small) ledge; the others are not, because (2) is 'downward-facing' and the others are vertical.

Nothing can be compared between the rock ledge and the room bump-outs you show. Nothing. They are completely different kettles of fish.

I’m voting to close this question because it is based on an inaccurate assumption.

A handhold in mountaineering

What word would you call something sticking out as in the pictures below?

Projection is a common word that can be used for all the photographs. Other words are bulge, protrusion, overhang, jut out.
If as shown in the picture if it is related to mountaineering it is called a handhold..

Ref. https://images.app.goo.gl/S8Hhwm3vD9WKr3NV6


These are called handholds.
Rocks sticking out from the ground are called outcroppings.

Ref. Cambridge dictionary
1.handhold
noun [ C ].
a thing you can hold on to with your hand as a support when climbing
2.bulge
noun [ C ].
a curved shape sticking out from the surface of something:
I wondered what the bulge in her coat pocket was.
to stick out in a round shape:
3.project verb (STICK OUT).
to stick out over an edge or from a surface:
4.protrude.
to stick out from a place or surface.
5.jut..
to (cause to) stick out, especially above or past the edge or surface of something:
6.ooverhang verb [T] (STICK OUT).
to stick out over something at a lower level:
7.outcrop.
noun [ C ].
a large rock or group of rocks that sticks out of the ground


(2) is a beam; (3) and (4) are columns.   These are building structures integrated into the ceiling slab and the walls.
Edit
We could call them protrusions.
Applying this to
(2) to (4), we could say beam protrusions or column protrusions.
Other than this, for an artificial climbing wall, we could call them grips or holds, as Wikipedia calls them:

A climbing wall is an artificially constructed wall with manufactured grips (or "holds") for the hands and feet.


See my explanatory update about (1) please at the end of the original post.

Perhaps "beam" and "column" are the things which created sticking out. But the question is about what sticking out itself is called.

You wrote: "we could say beam protrusions or column protrusions". Would it be correct to call them horizontal protrusions and vertical protrusions? Thanks.

A protrusion is simply a thing that protrudes, so as far as that goes it makes sense to say "a horizontal protrusion." The word "protrusion" is very generic in a way that makes it unlikely that a native speaker would choose it for any of these individual examples though. It sounds cold, scientific, or just plain a little bit weird.

A flat wall and a wall that isn't flat. I'm not sure that in building/construction, these would be referred to as protusions. I'm trying to think of a better term. The horizontal or vertical wall panels do not lie flat in the wall plane. The technical term is a bump-out (see the Engineering site).

@Lambie Completely agree. I think the problem is that all the things the user wants a word for don't form a natural category in English. Unless there's an uncommon but natural word that's just escaping us, I think any recommendation is going to be some combination of in-apt and unnatural.

@YonKuma There is nothing in common between a handhold in climbing and a bump-out in apartment or house design.
